# Timeseries Analysis: Stationary Process - How can you predict

Tags: time-series, stationarity

So I've read a lot on stationary processes and how we need to make sure the time series is stationary. Below I've linked the resources I've been going through.

I get that you can then predict a stationary process because then the statistical properties are just the same as they have been in the past, thus you can use the past data to help you estimate the future.

But intuitively/conceptually I'm confused. Because for a stationary process - in the long run there is no discernible trend or cycle. And if there is no perceivable pattern how can we hope to predict what it will do in the future? I.e it seems like within some range of values the process has been basically random over time in order to have constant statistical properties for any time 't'. Is it just a matter of  basically trying to mirror it's past behavior using fine tuned lag variables etc..?

Let me know if I'm missing a key part of understanding stationarity etc..

Resources I've used: [1](https://otexts.org/fpp2/), [2](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-random-walk-times-series-forecasting-python/), [3](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc442.htm), [4](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411diff.htm).